# Update item in database without all of the columns set in ContentValues

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

For example, I have four columns: `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number` and `picture`. Somewhere in my code there's:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MyPerson.FIRST_NAME, "Ted");
values.put(MyPerson.LAST_NAME, "Johnson");
values.put(MyPerson.PHONE_NUMBER, "111-111-1111");
values.put(MyPerson.PICTURE, "file://tedpicture.jpeg");

getContentResolver().update(tedUri, values, null, null);
```

Could I run something like:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MyPerson.PHONE_NUMBER, "222-222-2222");

getContentResolver().update(tedUri, values, null, null);
```

And expect the `first_name`,`last_name`, and `picture` columns to have the same values as when I first set them. Or do I have to also populate the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `picture` columns too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you can pass just one field of data to the update and it will update that column without affecting any others.

The problem you currently have, by the looks of it, you are not telling the DB which record you want to update.

As per the update method:

`public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`

You are passing null for the where part of the method.

If you pass a where part to the method it will update just the specific entry(s).

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MyPerson.PHONE_NUMBER, "222-222-2222");
getContentResolver().update(tedUri, values, "first_name = ?", new String[] { "tom" });
```

Would update anyone with the first name **tom** to have the phone number 222-222-2222

Answer (score 0):

That would work exactly as you described, only set values will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set where clause in update function 3rd parameter

```
getContentResolver().update(tedUri, values, "first_name=?", new String
         [ ]{"name"});
```