# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments. 5 arguments were provided but the statement needs 4 arguments

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update an entry in my DB however I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  5 arguments were provided but the statement needs 4 arguments.

Below the code:

```
int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentInsulinaUri, values, null, null);
```

values variable contains only 4 values and so it says in the log.
Logs are below:

```
09-19 09:30:17.167 19589-19589/com.example.android.insulina V/EditorActivity: values size is: 4 
09-19 09:30:17.168 19589-19589/com.example.android.insulina V/EditorsActivity: values are: opis=waga cukier=100 nazwa=kasza jednostki=6
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update item in database without all of the columns set in ContentValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706638/update-item-in-database-without-all-of-the-columns-set-in-contentvalues)

Comment: the values are included in the `values` variable. Can you post what the `values` variable contain? It should be a `ContentValues` with 5 elements and not 4. You can check this by calling `values.size()`

Comment: Below the logs:
09-19 09:30:17.167 19589-19589/com.example.android.insulina V/EditorActivity: values size is: 4
09-19 09:30:17.168 19589-19589/com.example.android.insulina V/EditorsActivity: values are: opis=waga cukier=100 nazwa=kasza jednostki=6

Answer (score 0):

I had found an typo in my Provider file, maybe this will be useful for someone:

```
selection = InsulinaContract.InsulinaEntry._ID + **"=?"**;
selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
return updateEntry(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
```

I was missing the "=?" in my selection declaration.